# iOS app in background (some sort of proxy)

Tags: ios, background

I need to implement some sort of proxy/tunnel application for iOS.  This app should be online all time, even if it executed in background.

Please give me some direction for further investigation .
AFAIK iOs only fire some callbacks, in app, for signaling about transition from background to foreground and vise-versa.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: proxy? like VPN? apple will not let your app to appstore otherwise

Comment: Like stunnel (with additional encryption and obfuscating). So I'm going to pass openvpn traffic via my secure tunnel.